# How to prevent routing in blazor

Tags: c#, asp.net, blazor

I create a nested layout in blazer.

blazor route to one of the navigation menus, and there is another menu in it.

When I click the navigation menu, it is routed to a specific page,
There is another menu on the routed page.

Clicking that menu loads the newly routed page in the nested layout.

However, clicking the topmost menu again loads the top route into the innermost layout.

Here is my code.

MainLayout.razor:

```
@inherits LayoutComponentBase

<div class="sidebar">
    <NavMenu />
</div>

<div class="main">
    <div class="top-row px-4">
        <a href="https://learn.microsoft.com/aspnet/" target="_blank">About</a>
    </div>

    <div class="content px-4">
        @Body
    </div>
</div>
```

NavMenu.razor:

```
<li class="nav-item px-3">
    <NavLink class="nav-link" href="sub">
        <span class="oi oi-list-rich" aria-hidden="true"></span> Sub
    </NavLink>
</li>
```

SubMenu.razor:

```
@page "/sub"

@layout MainLayout
@inherits LayoutComponentBase

<h3>SubLayout</h3>

<div style="width:20%">
    <ul class="nav flex-column">
        <li class="nav-item px-3">
            <NavLink class="nav-link" href="/sub/mypage" Match="NavLinkMatch.All">
                <span class="oi oi-account-login" aria-hidden="true"></span> go to sub of sub
            </NavLink>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>

<div style="width: 40%; height:40%; border:solid red">
    @Body
</div>
```

Mypage.razor:

```
@page "/sub/mypage"
@layout SubLayout

<div >
    <h3>This is Mypage</h3>
</div>
```

This is the execution result:

[image]

Why is the page in the top navigation menu loaded into the sublayout?
Is there any way to prevent this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Without seeing your SubLayout you are specifying in `Mypage.razor` I think the issue is that your trying to use a routable component as a layout. I basically just separated these.

`SubMenu.razor`

```
@page "/sub"

<SubLayout />
```

`SubLayout.razor`

Note the nesting by specifying `@layout MainLayout`

```
@layout MainLayout
@inherits LayoutComponentBase

<h3>SubLayout</h3>

<div style="width:20%">
    <ul class="nav flex-column">
        <li class="nav-item px-3">
            <NavLink class="nav-link" href="/sub/mypage" Match="NavLinkMatch.All">
                <span class="oi oi-account-login" aria-hidden="true"></span> go to sub of sub
            </NavLink>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>

<div style="width: 40%; height:40%; border:solid red">
    @Body
</div>
```

[image]

Docs are [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/layouts?view=aspnetcore-3.1)

Comment: Thank you for the reply. The layout is just a layout. Not the page to be routed...i understand